# I want to use two queries into one using a column from first query in the second one in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count

I have these two queries :

The first one :

```
SELECT * FROM item, user WHERE item_def = '289' 
    AND item_quality = '6' AND user.steam_64 = item.steam_64
```

The second one :

```
select count(item_id) from item where steam_64 = '".$steam_id64."'"
```

So basically, my first query is returning the users for the matching item (in this case item = 289). My second query is just looking how many items in total has every user returned in the first query .

I would like to have that count in the first query.

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy the second query and paste it into the select list of the first.

```
SELECT
  item.*,
  user.*,
  (select count(item_id) from item where steam_64 = '$steamid64') AS `count`
FROM
  item
INNER JOIN
  user
ON
  item.steam_64 = user.steam_64
WHERE
  item.item_quality = 6
AND
  item.item_def = 289
```

I feel like a mother saying to her child *eat your vegetables*, but... *write out your joins and don't quote your numbers*.

Comment: Ok i tried your query but i have 0 for every row in the count column. My count query is using the php variable $steamid64 which is the steam_64 of every row from the first query.

Comment: should be something like this: SELECT
  item.* as 'test',
  user.*,
  (select count(item_id) from item where steam_64 = test.steam_64) AS `count`
FROM
  item
INNER JOIN
  user
ON
  item.steam_64 = user.steam_64
WHERE
  item.item_quality = 6
AND
  item.item_def = 289

Comment: Doesn't this add a sub-select for each row returned?

Comment: @KevinBedell MySQL will only execute that subquery once even though its result will be put into every result row. If you run this query with `EXPLAIN`, you'll see on the `SUBQUERY` line: `Select tables optimized away`. The optimizer knows the difference between a dependent subquery (one which references some row-specific value) and an independent one which only needs to be run once.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is simply a matter of adding a GROUP BY clause since all you're interested from the second table is just the count.

Putting an additional SELECT statement in the main SELECT statement will cause an additional SELECT query to be done **for every row returned** -- which could lengthen query time dramatically.

Here's how I'd to this:

```
SELECT
  count (*) as count_of_items,
  user.*
FROM
  user join item on item.steam_64 = user.steam_64 
WHERE item.item_quality = 6 AND item.item_def = 289
GROUP BY user.steam_64
```

The GROUP BY clause just has to be done based on some column that's the same for every joined row.

Comment: No, adding the subquery does not cause it to execute for every row returned. MySQL will optimize away non-dependent subqueries; it only gets run once, while providing the desired output. Your query, on the other hand, does not provide the desired information at all (the list of items of quality 6 and def 289), nor the count he wanted (items owned by user $steamid64, of all types), nor does it attempt to combine them (which was the question we were to be answering).

Comment: After looking at this again I realized that in fact you are correct and my statement that the sub-select would be re-run for every row was incorrect. There are times when that's true and sub-selects are re-run for each row, but this is not one of them. Thank  you for pointing this out.